# How to add a string of text into another txt file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have this txt file that contains this text:

MSH^~|\&^R3POCQUERYS^050~BCMABU.MED.VA.GOV~DNS^R3POCQUERYR^^201711081317040500^^RQC~I06^50279320^D^2.5^^^AL^NE^USA

QRD^20171108131704-0500^R^I^WQRY^^^^SSN~%**ABC123**^9A-MED~**WA0034**^^^T

but I only want the values that come after SSN~% and after the MED~

I want to be able read from the Line that starts with QRD and then be able to grab **ANY** value after SSN~% and MED~, so the value can be anything I'm just using ABC123 and WA0034 as examples.

**Form1.cs**

```
private void Parse(string filename)
        {
            string line;
            var str = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            targetRichTextBox = richTextBox1;
            WriteTextSafelyInRichTextBox(str);


            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((line.Contains("QRD"))
                {
                    //Enter code here
                }
            }
            char[] delimiterChars = { '^' };
            string[] words = str.Split(delimiterChars);
            var createText = (RetrunTemplate.Get().Replace(words[24], "VHIC-").Replace(words[25], "9A-MED~WA0034"));
            var outputFilename = outputDir + "\\OutboundMessage - " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss-ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".txt";
            File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, createText);
            targetRichTextBox = richTextBox2;
            WriteTextSafelyInRichTextBox(createText);
            file.Close();
            File.Delete(filename);
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfuly creatd an outbound Message");
        }
```

**RetrunTemplate**

```
class RetrunTemplate
    {
        public static string Get()
        {
            string retrunTemplate = @"MSH^~|\&^R3POCSEND^442~CHEY209.FO-BAYPINES.MED.VA.GOV~DNS^R3POCRCV^^20171108131710-0400^^RCL~I06^442157252912^D^2.5^^^AL^NE^USA" + Environment.NewLine +
"PID^^^4420041228V165312~~~USVHA&&0363~NI~VA FACILITY ID&442&L~~20171108|666393848~~~" + Environment.NewLine +

@"USSSA&&0363~SS~VA FACILITY ID&442&L|""~~~USDOD&&0363~TIN~VA FACILITY ID&442&L" + Environment.NewLine +

@"""~~~USDOD&&0363~FIN~VA FACILITY ID&442&L|7209344~~~USVHA&&0363~PI~VA FACILITY ID&442&L" + Environment.NewLine +

@"^VHIC-ABC123~~~USVHA&&0363~PI~VA FACILITY ID&742V1&L^ZEIGLER~PG~EIGHT~~~~L" + Environment.NewLine +

@"|""~~~~~~N^^19220304^M^^^9234234~""~SAN FRANCISCO~CA~94114~USA~P~""~075|~~SAN JOSE~CO~~""~N^^""^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" + Environment.NewLine +

@"PV1^^^9A-MED" + Environment.NewLine + "HH1^WA0034";

            return retrunTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the name of this format? It looks like the initial section specifies some delimiters. It looks like HL7.  Parsing by the rules is always preferable. Using RegEx could easily fail on some quoting or escaping rule.

Comment: It is an hl7 message but I don't want anything to be hardcoded. I want this to be dynamic. Because the text inside the text file may change but the formatting will always be the same like: "^", "~", MED~, and "SSN~%". The only information I want to extract from the QRD line are the characters in between the SSN~% and "^", and the characters in between MED~ and ^.

Comment: Still, breaking it up the HL7 way is the only way to be safe. Look for a parser ot `String.Split()` it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you read the file line by line. You can validate each line against the following `Regex`, and extract what you want.

```
var text = "QRD^20171108131704-0500^R^I^WQRY^^^^SSN~%ABC123^9A-MED~WA0034^^^T";
var rgx = new Regex(@"QRD.+SSN~%(.+)MED~(.+)");
var match = rgx.Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

The `match.Groups[1]` has `ABC123^9A-`, and `match.Groups[2]` has `WA0034^^^T`. You can now do what you will with those text.

### Regex Breakdown

> @"QRD.+SSN~%(.+)MED~(.+)"

- `QRD` - Starts with the string `QRD`
- `.+` - Followed by one or more characters
- `SSN~%` - Followed by `SSN~~%`
- `(.+)` - Grab (to Groups[1]) one or more characters between `SSN~%` and `MED~`
- `MED!` - Followed by `MED~`
- `(.+)` - Grab everything else in the line to `Groups[2]`

Comment: I don't want anything to be hardcoded, I want this to be dynamic. Because the text inside the text file may change but the formatting will always be the same like: "^", "~", MED~, and "SSN~%". The only information I want to extract from the QRD line are the characters in between the SSN~% and "^", and the characters in between MED~ and ^.

Comment: You didn't make that clear earlier; before you said you wanted to extract stuff between SSN and MED. Still this regex isn't hardcoded and still have all you need to edit it to fix your need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my effort.

```
var input = @"MSH^~|\&^R3POCQUERYS^050~BCMABU.MED.VA.GOV~DNS^R3POCQUERYR^^201711081317040500^^RQC~I06^50279320^D^2.5^^^AL^NE^USA

QRD^20171108131704-0500^R^I^WQRY^^^^SSN~%ABC123^9A-MED~WA0034^^^T" ;

var pattern = @"SSN\~\%([A-Z0-9]+).*MED\~([A-Z0-9]+)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).
            Select( m => new { SSN = m.Groups[1].Value, MED = m.Groups[2].Value});

foreach(var m in matches ) {
    Console.WriteLine($"SSN = {m.SSN}, MED = {m.MED}");
}
```

### Output

```
SSN = ABC123, MED = WA0034
```

## With QRD matching

```
var input = @"MSH^~|\&^R3POCQUERYS^050~BCMABU.MED.VA.GOV~DNS^R3POCQUERYR^^201711081317040500^^RQC~I06^50279320^D^2.5^^^AL^NE^USA

QRD^20171108131704-0500^R^I^WQRY^^^^SSN~%ABC123^9A-MED~WA0034^^^T";

var pattern = @"SSN\~\%([A-Z0-9]+).*MED\~([A-Z0-9]+)";

var matches = input
    .Split()
    .Where(l => l.StartsWith("QRD"))
    .Select(l => Regex.Matches(l, pattern).Select(m => new { SSN = m.Groups[1].Value, MED = m.Groups[2].Value }));

foreach (var groups in matches)
{
    foreach (var g in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SSN = {g.SSN}, MED = {g.MED}");
    }
}
```

### Output

```
SSN = ABC123, MED = WA0034
```